# How do i serlialize the product using php?

Tags: php, mysql

i am building a real estate application where in it will store the properties and search it. the property will have different categories like (residential, commercial, industrial or agricultural). based upon the category i want to serailize each and every property listing . for example the property with id 1 belongs to resedential will have the serial code rs_SOMERANDOMUNIQUENUMBER. and for commercial it can be cm_SOMERANDOMUNIQUENUMBER and so on. for this my database table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propSerials` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`serial` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`property_id` int(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

what would be the best possible format to store the serial with the prefix according to category?

thank you

Comment: I just finished a property app, but why are you storing the serailized data? Its petty useless, especially when its stored elsewhere anyway and you cannot effectively search the data stored in it.

Comment: I think by 'serialize' he means 'assign a serial number' not 'store in serialized form'

Comment: my client want it this way because he wants to have something called unique reference number for every property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you add another column that holds category_id and in category table add column with prefixes for that category.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propSerials` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`serial` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`property_id` int(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propCategories` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`property_prefix` char(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In query you can:

```
SELECT CONCAT('prefix_', 'serial');
```

Comment: Concat can decrease performance..  If you go this route just combine the columns in php